# Update table according to matches found in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having a heavy brain freeze here, all help is welcome.

Background info: working on a search function that should return the number of occurrences of one or multiple (user provided) keywords based on matches in another table.

The first table will actually be a temporary table inside a table function but for the sake of simplicity, let's make it a regular table.

```
CREATE TABLE search_query {
  keyword VARCHAR (30),
  occurrences INT
}
```

That "table" will contain the (sanitized) keywords the user provides. For example:

```
keyword occurrences
HOW     0
TO      0
CODE    0
THIS    0
```

"occurences" is 0 by default.

My second table contains a record for each significant keyword a product can have.

```
CREATE TABLE product_keywords {
  productId INT,
  keyword VARCHAR(30)
}
```

Sample data:

```
productId  keyword
12         HOW
12         NOT
12         CODE
13         RANDOM
13         THIS
13         CODE
```

What I'm trying to do is build a query that will UPDATE the "occurrences" field in search_query based on keyword matches with product_keywords.

In this example, after the query runs, search_query should contain

```
HOW    1
TO     0
CODE   2
THIS   1
```

My efforts so far stranded because for the life of me, I can't figure out how to build the JOIN necessary for the update. I'm about here:

```
UPDATE destination_table
SET destination_table.occurrences = JN.matches
FROM search_query AS destination_table
INNER JOIN  [where I freeze] AS JN
WHERE ....
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks, Chris

Comment: I suggest to  create a view to avoid running update every time table1's rows changed

Comment: @LukaszSzozda not sure I'm getting your point: search_query would have to be updated every time a search query is performed. The ultimate goal is to sum up occurrences to know if any keyword matched, and sort search results by relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a subquery to return the matches and join it to the table:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.occurrences = g.counter
FROM search_query s INNER JOIN (
  SELECT s.keyword, COUNT(*) counter
  FROM search_query s INNER JOIN product_keywords p 
  ON p.keyword = s.keyword
  GROUP BY s.keyword
) g ON g.keyword = s.keyword
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13b4dcb4335248bc2615dbfcf10fc1d6).
Or for readability you could use a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.keyword, COUNT(*) counter
  FROM search_query s INNER JOIN product_keywords p 
  ON p.keyword = s.keyword
  GROUP BY s.keyword
)
UPDATE s
SET s.occurrences = c.counter
FROM search_query s INNER JOIN cte c 
ON c.keyword = s.keyword
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e271ec203675605b86cc348279e3b4e0).
Results:

```
> keyword | occurrences
> :------ | ----------:
> HOW     |           1
> TO      |           0
> CODE    |           2
> THIS    |           1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! This works like a breeze and you've just saved me a lot of frustration. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery with `UPDATE` might be the simplest and fastest approach:

```
update search_query
    set occurrences = (select count(*)
                       from product_keywords pk
                       where pk.keyword = search_query.keyword
                      );
```

For performance, you want an index on `product_keywords(keywords)`.

Comment: *might be the simplest* maybe, maybe not. *might be the fastest* no way.